# RVM troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rvm

I am trying to fix my RVM.  Last week everything was working fine but today for some reason my rails commands are not working.  For example, if I try:

```
rails new blog
```

I get this error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/version (LoadError)
```

Is this because my ruby version is outdated? does anyone know how I could fix this?  I looked all over and only found the rvm get stable command however that did not fix my issue.  Thank you to anyone that knows what is going on here.

Sorry for the bad formatting, here you go.

```
 here is ruby -v:
```

`

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

here is the error I get with rails -v:

```
/home/tyrel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_e‌​xt/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/version (LoadError)
```

here is rvm list:

rvm rubies ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ] ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ] =* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ] ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ] # => - current # =* - current && default # * - default

Comment: Few things to try. What do you get when u type 'ruby -v' & 'rails -v', also 'rvm list'

Comment: I know I have installed rails though so I have no idea why this started happening, I have been working on this machine with ruby on rails for months=( have no idea why my rails just stopped workingT.T

Comment: Dude, put that in a pastie, or add it to the question so its formatted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, output is in my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help but upon further research I found what I needed to do.

First I ran:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Then I found another post on here that recommended trying this:

You need to run the follow

user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
then run this

user$ type rvm | head -n 1
and if you get

rvm is a function
the problem is solved.

You also need to run user$ rvm requirements to see dependency requirements for your operating system

Source: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

I forget mention that you need to put this code into you ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file and you will not need to write this code again. Cheers!  -Jorge Garcia

After all that my RVM was fixed, and I can use my rails new projectname command.

Thanks for all the help community!!!<3